# Override dependency object prototype in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, loopbackjs

I have a set of angular `$resource` defined in a module called 'App.API' in a single file  which I cannot touch because it is generated. (With `loopback-angular`, a tool to generate angular $resource from server side model definitions)

Let's take the `Product` dependency as en example, later in the app, I want to override its prototype, like this :

```
module('App.NewModule', ['App.API']).run(['Product', function(Product) {
    Product.prototype.getTitle = function() {
        return 'Product name is ' + this.name;
    };
    // From now on I can use p.getTitle() on every Product $resource
});
```

It works.

The thing is, I have many different files, each containing modules, and I am experiencing a dependency injection issue : I can access the `getTitle` function inside `NewModule`, *but not inside other modules*.

**Question : How can I override a dependency object prototype and make it available to other modules ?**

I tried to define the prototype functions in this way instead, thinking that `Product` prototype would be modified. *Maybe not early enough* :

```
module('App.API').run(['Product', function(Product) {
    Product.prototype.getTitle = function() {
        return 'Product name is ' + this.name;
    };
});
```

It does not work : using `getTitle` in another module (using App.API/Product as a dependency) on a `Product` instance still throws a `undefined is not a function` error, even while `Product` object is correctly injected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just messed up the dependency definitions / orders.

I have three files :

1. `app.js` for module `App` (dependant on module `App.API`)
2. `api.js` for module `App.API`
3. `product.js` containing `Product` prototype

As stated in the question, I was doing :

```
// in product.js
module('App.API').run(['Product', function(Product) { ... }]);

// in app.js
var appModule = module('App', ['App.API']);
```

But the `App.API` module was defined in another file, which is a bit messed up because you never know for sure which one will load first, unless dealing with in in the js loader and loosing parallel downloads.

So I explicitly specified the modules and dependencies, at the expense of adding more dependency to declare in my app (but it works and is more stable) :

```
// in product.js
module('ApiProduct', ['App.API']).run(['Product', function(Product) { ... }]);

// in app.js
var appModule = module('App', ['App.API', 'ApiProduct']);
```

*Note : In my first attempt, I defined the prototype in a new module in a `.config()` block, but it was not working, maybe because `App.API` services were not loaded yet. With `.run()` it works and my `getTitle` prototype is available everywhere I need `Product` provider.*

Comment: You might also want to tak a look at `$provide.decorator()`.